# Go to a specific slide with iDangerous Swiper

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

If I have a custom menu.

How can I go to a specific slide at any moment in Swiper.js?

```
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li class="slide-3">go to slide 3</li>
    <li class="slide-5">go to slide 5</li>
    <li class="slide-1">go to slide 1</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I tried something like this but is not working:

```
$('.slide-3').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".menu .active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    swipeTo( $('.pag2').index() );
});
```

Comment: I know it's an old question, but it is good etiquette to mark an answer correct! :) But a user with only 1 question in 2 years might not come back either.

Answer (score 23):

From the [documentation](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) page:

```
mySwiper.slideTo(index, speed, runCallbacks);
```

Run transition to the slide with index number equal to 'index' parameter for the speed equal to 'speed' parameter. You can set 'runCallbacks' to false (by default it is 'true') and transition will not produce onSlideChange callback functions.

So in your case, you first need to declare a variable for example:

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: false
});
```

And then:

```
$('.slide-3').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".menu .active").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    mySwiper.slideTo( $('.pag2').index(),1000,false );
});
```

Comment: @ImranBughio you are right, documentation has changed since I wrote the answer. I have updated it ;) thanks!

Comment: Note: If you are using Swiper v2 you need to use `swipeTo()` instead of `slideTo()`

Comment: yes @BadHorsie but they changed that feature on v3 are they are on v3.3.1 now

Comment: I know, that's what I'm saying. I had to work on a website which used v2.

Answer (score 8):

To build on Ahmed's answer, to implement:

```
var moveToClickedNumber = function(swiper){swiper.swipeTo(swiper.clickedSlideIndex)}

var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container',{
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: false,
    onSlideClick: moveToClickedNumber,
    initialSlide: 0, //slide number which you want to show-- 0 by default
});
```

Comment: as of the v3.x this was implemented directly into the API.

Answer (score 8):

As of the v3.0.x version, this has been baked into the API.

Simply initialize with `slideToClickedSlide:true` in your config. (defaults to false)

That's it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get this to work. All my slides are loaded in dynamically - I wonder if that's why it doesn't work for me.

Comment: @rpivovar try making a new question, with your specific code example and referencing this question.

Answer (score 2):

```
 function goToPage(numberPage){
  new Swiper('.swiper-container').slideTo(numberPage,1000,false)
}


goToPage(10);
```

Comment: Its very simple, save my time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use built in callbacks

http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/api.php

mySwiper.clickedSlideIndex - returns the index number of touched/clicked slide. For use only with "onSlideTouch" and "onSlideClick" callbacks.

mySwiper.clickedSlide - returns the touched/clicked slide (slide instance, HTMLElement). For use only with "onSlideTouch" and "onSlideClick" callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the answers above, for those who are using the thumbs gallery, you have to add `.slideTo(index, 0, false);` in your top Swiper only.

Here is an example on how to implement it:

```
// Use your own classes and index variable
var swiperThumbs = new Swiper(".mySwiperThumbs", {
  loop: true
});

var swiperTop = new Swiper(".mySwiperTop", {
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: swiperThumbs,
  },
}).slideTo(index, 0, false);
```